# Django Operational Error 1405 Upon syncdb

Tags: python, mysql, django, mamp

I'm trying to move over from SQLite3 to MySQL, after much difficulty I finally got MySQL-python working however when I try to run `./manage.py syncdb` I get an error

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Right now I'm running MySQL through MAMP. I tried creating a new user instead of using root but I get the same error. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'db17',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'root',
    'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
    'PORT': '8889',                      # Set to empty string for default.
}
```

}

Those are the settings given by MAMP.

Comment: Have you properly filled the database section in your settings.py file ?

Comment: I believe so, let me update my question with that info.

Comment: Are you sure that you server is running on the port 8889 ?

Comment: 8889 is the port given by MAMP and I tried that (it was suggested in another stack post) but that gives the same error.

Comment: Try to connect from the command line (following this for instance : http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/08/using-mysql-command-line-with-mamp.html).

Comment: That worked fine, but I'm not sure what that means in regards to the issue I'm having though.

Comment: Have you tried this :  

    'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',

Found here : http://tom.londondroids.com/2012/05/setting-up-django-with-mamp-on-mac-os-x-lion-in-steps/

Comment: Great that seemed to do the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating a new user, did you also grant that user permissions on the tables in your project?

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db17.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Yes I did when I created the user.